# I can't create a python 3.8 environment in anaconda

Tags: anaconda, python-3.8

I'm new to the community so thank you for any support you could give me. My question:

I tried to create a new anaconda environment for python 3.8 with

```
(base) C:\Users\user>conda create -n My_Env_py38 python=3.8 anaconda
```

After it tries to solve the environment it fails and I get the following message:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package python conflicts for:
python=3.8
anaconda -> anaconda-project==0.8.3=py_0 -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=3.5|>=3.6|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|3.7.*']
anaconda -> python[version='2.7.13|2.7.14|2.7.14|2.7.15|2.7.15|2.7.16|3.6.9|3.7.4|3.6.8|3.7.3|3.7.3|3.6.7|3.7.1|3.7.0|3.6.6|3.6.5|3.5.5|3.6.4|3.5.4|3.6.3|3.5.4|3.6.2|3.5.4|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0',build='h6679aeb_11|hb034564_12|h59f5a59_20|hdec4e59_20|h9e2ca53_1|h8c3f1cb_23|h0c2934d_2|hea74fb7_0|hea74fb7_0|he216670_0|hcb6e200_5|h8c8aaf0_6|h8c8aaf0_0|h9f7ef89_7|h5263a28_0|h5500b2f_0|hcb6e200_0|h8c8aaf0_1|h9f7ef89_2|h0c2934d_0|h6538335_1|h1357f44_23|hd3c4935_11']
```

I've updated anaconda. (And it has been working fine with python 3.7.6 before and after the update)
I've also tried to install python 3.8 in the current environment and anaconda can't solve the environment either.
Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's an anaconda distribution for 3.8 out yet.

Comment: Thank you very much @cel I may need to just wait a bit. It's more than enough for me to use py 3.7; but I thought the dates for the python update and the anaconda distribution were more aligned; since I'm new to both, I assumed there was something wrong with my process.

Comment: From Anaconda site : article on 2020.02 release explains: "As there are still some key OSS projects that aren’t available or stable for Python 3.8, the installers are based around Python 3.7. Notably, at the time of this release, Tensorflow does not yet support Python 3.8, so installers based around Python 3.8 would cause problems for users who want to use Tensorflow. There are Python 3.6 and Python 3.8 metapackages available with this release, so you can work with Anaconda in other versions of Python as you wish."
source: https://www.anaconda.com/anaconda-individual-edition-2020-02/

Answer (score 0):

I finally created a new environment from the Anaconda navigator; I didn't specify the python version, so it created it with python 3.7.6.
Then (again from the navigator) I updated the python version (to 3.8.1); it seems to work fine.
For some reason it hadn't worked before when I tried to update the existing environment or to create a new one from the command prompt; not sure if it's possible now, but this alternative worked.